# Oracle APEX hide the x on the modal dialog

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I tried to hide the `x` on the upper right-hand corner of my modal dialog window using both css and JQuery but nothing owrks. I tries using dynamic action on page load:

```
$("button.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget.ui-button-icon-only.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
```

and to use css:

```
button.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-icon-only.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

for my inline css but neither worked, the x still shows up

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The div where this button is showed is rendered in the parent page, so to get it in the modal page, you need to add "parent" in the beginning of your javarscript.

try this:

```
var button = parent.$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); //get the button
button.hide(); //hide the button
```

Comment: I do not recommend doing this. It's always best to build your page so you do not need changes like this. If you want to close your modal after running a process, then you can create a process to close the modal.